# Accessing Props to Map over Array in React Child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

Been working with react and still trying to grasp all the concepts. Could use help to understand how I can get this to work. I want to pass an array as props to another react component to map over. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? I can map through the array as a function but not inside render:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Leaf from './components/Leaf';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewport: {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        latitude: 40.7128,
        longitude: -74.0060,
        zoom: 10
      },
      latitude: 40.7128,
      longitude: -74.0060,
      zoom: 10,
      stations: [],
      selectedStation: null,
      userLocation: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gbfs.citibikenyc.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res=>
      this.setState({stations: res}))
  }

  checkData=()=>{
    console.log(this.state.stations)
    this.state.stations.data.stations.map(e=>{
      console.log(e)
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={this.checkData}>click me</button>   
          <Leaf 
            viewport={this.state.viewport}
            stations={this.state.stations}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**leaf.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class leaf extends Component {

    checkData=()=>{
        this.props.stations.data.stations.map(e=>{
          console.log(e)
        })
      }



    render() {

        const markers = this.props.stations.data.stations.map((station) =>
        <Marker 
          position={[station.lat, station.lon]}
          onClick={this.markerClick.bind(this,station)}>
          <Popup>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
              );


        const position = [this.props.viewport.latitude, this.props.viewport.longitude]
        //const position = [40.7484, -73.9857]
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.checkData}>check props</button>
                <Map center={position} zoom={14}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    {markers}
                    <Marker position={position}>
                        <Popup>
                            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </Map>  
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default leaf;
```

In the past I've done something like :

```
const Search = ( props ) => {
return (
)
}
```

But I am looking to understand how to make this work using `class leaf extends Component` . Appreciate the help.

**Data Structure for Reference**

```
    {
    last_updated: 1572631066,
    ttl: 10,
    data: {
    stations: [
    {
    station_id: "237",
    external_id: "66db3c29-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c",
    name: "E 11 St & 2 Ave",
    short_name: "5746.04",
    lat: 40.73047309,
    lon: -73.98672378,
    region_id: 71,
    rental_methods: [
    "CREDITCARD",
    "KEY"
    ],
    capacity: 39,
    rental_url: "http://app.citibikenyc.com/S6Lr/IBV092JufD?station_id=237",
    electric_bike_surcharge_waiver: false,
    eightd_has_key_dispenser: false,
    eightd_station_services: [
    {
    id: "e73b6bfb-961f-432c-a61b-8e94c42a1fba",
    service_type: "ATTENDED_SERVICE",
    bikes_availability: "UNLIMITED",
    docks_availability: "NONE",
    name: "Valet Service",
    description: "Citi Bike Station Valet attendant service available",
    schedule_description: "",
    link_for_more_info: "https://www.citibikenyc.com/valet"
    }
    ],
    has_kiosk: true
    },
    {
    station_id: "281",
    external_id: "66db5fae-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c",
    name: "Grand Army Plaza & Central Park S",
    short_name: "6839.10",
    lat: 40.7643971,
    lon: -73.97371465,
    region_id: 71,
    rental_methods: [
    "CREDITCARD",
    "KEY"
    ],
    capacity: 66,
    rental_url: "http://app.citibikenyc.com/S6Lr/IBV092JufD?station_id=281",
    electric_bike_surcharge_waiver: false,
    eightd_has_key_dispenser: true,
    eightd_station_services: [
    {
    id: "32461582-cd1e-4ecf-a5ea-563593fa7009",
    service_type: "ATTENDED_SERVICE",
    bikes_availability: "UNLIMITED",
    docks_availability: "NONE",
    name: "Valet Service",
    description: "Citi Bike Valet Attendant Service Available",
    schedule_description: "",
    link_for_more_info: "https://www.citibikenyc.com/valet"
    }
    ],
    has_kiosk: true
    }
]
}
}
```

**Attempts**

So here I changed the const markers to mirror the conosle.log from checkData:

```
const markers =  this.props.stations.data.stations.map((station) =>
        <Marker 
          position={[station.lat, station.lon]}
          onClick={this.markerClick.bind(this,station)}>
          <Popup>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
              );
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stations' of undefined

When I remove the markers variable and click checkData, notice that it has not issue mapping over and console logging the object:

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? Since you're passing App's `state.stations` as a prop named `stations`, in Leaf.js you just need to do `this.props.stations.map(() => {})`.

Comment: this.props.stations.map is not a function is the error with your suggestion. Also when I hit the button check props I can definitely iterate through the array and console log all the objects without issue. But for markers it won't map over since its inside the render piece. I've tried your suggestion as well as const markers = this.props.stations.data.stations.map(e=>{}) which gives me the error: Cannot read property 'stations' of undefined

Comment: My guess is that `stations` is changing its datatype between initialization and setting it from your request. It looks like its set to an array at first, but then set to an object with your array nested inside `data`. Can you `console.log` the `res` and post output?

Comment: I don't think it's changing because the checkData function in is able to console log the mapping of the array. I added in my edits. Unless I'm off here?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access data before the request finished?

Comment: Camilo: does that make sense considering that with the checkData function I am able to map over without issue?

Comment: I don't know but you can try rendering only if the data is available, just to make sure.

Comment: Camilo you are a genius, thank you very much for helping me with this!

Comment: I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I'd doublecheck that you're accessing the correct data properties, as in your function you're calling `this.props.stations.data.stations.map`, but in your render you're calling `this.props.stations.data.map`, so one must be incorrect.

Also, class components should be `PascalCase`, i.e. capitalized.

Comment: So I changed it to mirror but still not able to access it, still not luck.

Comment: If your function is logging the data successfully, the map should work. Can't say more without seeing the complete data structure.

Comment: Also, I unfortunately cannot view images hosted on Imgur here :(

Comment: yeah I've been stumped on this all day. I have a link to the image here as well if you can take a look (it shows the result of clicking the button check Props which shows I am accessing the right part of the array):  https://ibb.co/PZ29dgV

Comment: Link doesn't work. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: added data structure example of two objects in the array. I get the error: cannot read property 'stations' of undefined, Camilo in the other response mentioned it might be because the data is not available yet at render but not sure how to test that out.

Answer (score 0):

Camilo was correct and I needed to make sure data was available for render. Below is the working code:

**App.js**

```
//import logo from './logo.svg';
//import './App.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Leaf from './components/Leaf';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewport: {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        latitude: 40.7128,
        longitude: -74.0060,
        zoom: 10
      },
      latitude: 40.7128,
      longitude: -74.0060,
      zoom: 10,
      stations: [],
      showStations: false,
      selectedStation: null,
      userLocation: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const request = async()=> {
      await fetch('https://gbfs.citibikenyc.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res=>
        this.setState({stations: res, showStations: true}))
    }
    request();
  }

  checkData=()=>{
    console.log(this.state.stations)
    this.state.stations.data.stations.map(e=>{
      console.log(e)
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={this.checkData}>click me</button>   
          <Leaf 
            viewport={this.state.viewport}
            stations={this.state.stations}
            showStations={this.state.showStations}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Leaf.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
//import './leaf.css'
//import InfoBox from './InfoBox';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
//import Search from './Search';
//import Match from './Match';
//import Modal from './Modal';
//import L from 'leaflet';
//import Routing from "./RoutingMachine";
//import { Row, Col, Grid, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
//import ErrorBoundary from '../ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary'



class Leaf extends Component {


    checkData=()=>{
        this.props.stations.data.stations.map(e=>{
          console.log(e)
        })
      }

    render() {

        let markers =null;
        if(this.props.showStations) {
        markers = (
            <div>
            {
            this.props.stations.data.stations.map((station) =>
                <Marker 
                    position={[station.lat, station.lon]}>
                </Marker>
                )
            }
            </div>
        )
        }


        const position = [this.props.viewport.latitude, this.props.viewport.longitude]
        //const position = [40.7484, -73.9857]
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.checkData}>check props</button>
                <Map center={position} zoom={14}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                      {markers}
                    <Marker position={position}>
                        <Popup>
                            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </Map>  
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Leaf;
```